# How do I search my anki deck for cards before my script accidentally makes duplicates?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, interface, anki

so I'm trying to write a python script which takes a wordlist of Japanese words, finds example sentences online for those words and makes anki cards with those sentences, and marks words which there were no available sentences for.

My basic idea is to use selenium to webscrape sentences from Tangorin.com, and then use genanki to make cards but the problem is I want to write the script in such a way that if the sentence already exists in my anki deck, the script either takes the next sentence or if there isn't any more sentences just marks that word out as not having any sentences and moves on to the next word. The problem is I don't have any idea how to check the ongoing anki database to see whether or not a card exists.

When you add a duplicate to anki it recognises that its a duplicate by highlighting the field red like this:

[Anki Duplication Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IPDI.png)

So it seems clear that anki itself can recognise duplicate cards, and I want to write my program in a way that it also checks the sentence it's just pulled, sees if it's a duplicate card or not, and then if it is, skips over to the next available sentence, and if there isn't another available sentence just marks it as a no sentence available card for a separate report (for things I can manually add or forget about) and then moves onto the next word. I hope it's clear what I mean, apologies for not being more specific I only started learning to program this month.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]